# Are these values empty or null and how do I drop these columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

So I have this dataframe which looks like below:

```
+----------------+----------+-------------+-----------+---------+-------------+
|_manufacturerRef|_masterRef|_nomenclature|_partNumber|_revision|_serialNumber|
+----------------+----------+-------------+-----------+---------+-------------+
|            #id2|     #id19|             |   zaa01948|         | JTJHA31U2400|
|            #id2|     #id29|             |   zaa22408|         |         null|
|            #id2|     #id45|             |   zaa24981|         |         null|
+----------------+----------+-------------+-----------+---------+-------------+
```

I want to drop empty columns, which are `_nomenclature` and `_revision` as shown in the above dataframe. I am trying various methods but none would drop. No method is able to detect these columns as empty. Also, there might be the possibility that the columns can be of type Struct as well. I am trying like below:

```
 val cols = xmldf.columns
    cols.foreach(c => {
      var currDF = xmldf.select("`" + c + "`")
      currDF.show()
      val df1 = currDF.filter(currDF("`" + c + "`").isNotNull)
      if(df1.count() == 0 || df1.rdd.isEmpty()){
        xmldf = xmldf.drop(c)
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with your code is, that columns `_nomeclature` and `_revision` aren't really empty, they contain empty strings, not nulls. Because of that, you can't use `isNotNull` to check if the cell is empty, you need to use `=!=` operator.

You can also use `filter` and `foldLeft` instead of `foreach`, if you want to avoid using mutable `var`.

```
val df = List(("#id2","#id19", "", "zaa01947", "", "JTJHA31U2400"), ("#id2", "#id29", "", "zaa22408", "", null)).toDF("_manufacturerRef", "_masterRef", "_nomenclature", "_partNumber", "_revision", "_serialNumber")

val newDf = df.columns
   .filter(c => df.where(df(c) =!= "").isEmpty) //find column containing only empty strings
   .foldLeft(df)(_.drop(_)) //drop all found columns from dataframe

newDf.show()
```

And as expected, `_nomeclature` and `_revision` are dropped in result:

```
+----------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
|_manufacturerRef|_masterRef|_partNumber|_serialNumber|
+----------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
|            #id2|     #id19|   zaa01947| JTJHA31U2400|
|            #id2|     #id29|   zaa22408|         null|
+----------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment: but this code doesn't work if one of the column types is struct. It gives Analysis exception.

Comment: @CodeHunter In case you check `struct` column, then maybe cast it to `String`? Like this: `df.where(df(c).cast(StringType) =!= "").isEmpty`. Is this acceptable?